# ja used for a signed number instead of jg

Tags: c++, c, assembly, switch-statement, x86-64

```
void switch_eq(long x, long n, long *dest){
 long val = x;
 switch(n) {

  case 100:
  .
  .
  .
 }
```

In the text book, they suggested it is equivalent assembly code

```
switch_eg:

 subq $100, %rsi
 cmpq $6,  %rsi
 ja  .L8
 .
 .
 .
```

I think we'd better to use `jg`, not `ja`, since I think `$6` and `%rsi` are signed numbers. Am I wrong?

Comment: That's a neat trick to handle negative numbers since those appear as large positive numbers if treated unsigned. Thus you can use a single `ja` to check `100 <= x < 106`

Comment: You mean ja makes n-100 bigger or same with 0?

Comment: It is in the accepted answer there: *"So let's say n was less than 100, e.g. 99. If we then subtract 100 from that we get -1, which when viewed as an unsigned 32-bit value is 4294967295, which is obviously "above" 6, and the jump to .L2 is taken like it should."*

Comment: (I've edited the linked duplicate so that it becomes obvious that it asked this question too)